# Books on cluster algorithms

Tags: clustering, k-means

I'm searching for books on the basic k-means and divisive clustering algorithms. I'm interested in the pros and cons of both. It's a part of my bachelors thesis, I have implemented both and need books to create my used literature list for the theoretical part.
Also, is there a book on "the curse of dimensionality"? 
Thanks!

Comment: What books/sources did you actually use to find out about the techniques and implement them? This is what the literature should be about, I think. Padding it with stuff you didn't read makes no sense.

Comment: I used one book in my native tongue. I have checked: Data clustering: theory, algorithms, and applications. Data mining: concepts, models, methods and algorithms and Cluster Analysis, 5th edition. I don't need no padding, just a few books in which the algorithms are well described, with their pros and cons. For example: 1) the centroids in k-means tend to move closer to where there are more samples. 2) Due to the "cure of dimensionality", it's only possible to compare results with in the same data set. I just need ground to stand on, that I read that in a book, not thought of it myself ;)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with crediting a book in your native tongue, **if that is what you used**...

Comment: This was genius. Very useful.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.dcc.ufmg.br/miningalgorithms/files/pdf/fdma.pdf) is a book that's got a couple of them + very simple examples.

HTH

D

Comment: You should at least write the title / author of the book. I can't access the link right now.

Answer (score 2):

Almost any book on machine learning will explain you the so called "curse of dimensionality" problem. For example, the freely available and excellent [Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/). It also has a section on clustering algorithms, though probably not in all depth you may wish for.

Comment: I don't need depth as my main goal was to create the program for comparing both algorithms, need only basic stuff.